# How to remove a char from char array with index in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, char

I'm starting out with Kotlin.
I want to remove a specific charter of a charArray using indices.
For example if there's an array ar = (a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h), how do I remove ar[x] from it...?

Comment: You can't remove something from a CharArray. You can only replace it with another Char.

Answer (score 4):

as @Tenfour04 mentioned you can't remove element from an array. because it has fixed size. but you can make a new array without that element.

if array be [ a, b, c, d] for removing index 1 you can do this:

```
array = array.filterIndexed { i, _ -> i !== 1 }
```

now array is [ a, c, d ].

result of filterIndexed is a new list. if you explicitly want an array you have to convert the result like this:

```
array = array.filterIndexed { i, _ -> i !== 1 }.toCharArray()
```

or

```
array = array.filterIndexed { i, _ -> i !== 1 }.toTypedArray()
```

Comment: This is yet another demonstration of why people should prefer `List`s to `Array`s in Kotlin (and Java).  Of course, there are a few situations where you need an array: vararg lists, using an array-based API, squeezing every byte of memory, or implementing `ArrayList`.  But other than that, lists are much more flexible: they behave like other objects with decent `toString()` and equality; they have shedloads more extension methods; they're properly generic; they interoperate far better with the rest of the Collections API and other code…

Comment: Would it work if it was a String instead of charArray...???

Comment: yes it works with string too. but for string you can use removeRange(1..1)